# c++ Inheritance in different files error

Tags: c++, inheritance

For some reason I can't manage to figure out what is wrong with my inheritance in c++ within different files. The biggest error I get is 'no matching function for call to 'Enemy::Enemy (int&)'

Here is my Monster.cpp code

```
#include "Monster.h"
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <iostream>
Monster::Monster(int MonsterHealth,int MonsterMana,int Monstersize) // implementation
 : Health(MonsterHealth), Mana(MonsterMana), Enemy(Monstersize)
{}


int Monster::dropxp(int enemydropxp){


}
```

Here is my Monster.h

```
#ifndef MONSTER_H
#define MONSTER_H
#include "Enemy.h"

class Monster : public Enemy
{
    Monster();

Monster(int MonsterHealth, int MonsterMana,int Monstersize);
    void TheenemyHealth()
    {
        int Enemyhealth = 100;
    }
    int EnemyDamage(int EnemyAttack){
    int Attack = EnemyAttack;
    Attack = 5;
    }
    int dropxp(int enemyxpdrop);
    private:
   int Health = 0;
      int Mana = 0;
    };

#endif // MONSTER_H
```

Here is my enemy.cpp

```
#include "Enemy.h"

Enemy::Enemy(int EnemyHealth,int EnemyMana)
{
    Attackpower;
    Strenght;
    Enemyxp;

}

Enemy::~Enemy()
{
    //dtor
}
```

and my enemy.h

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H

class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy(int EnemyHealth,int EnemyMana);
    ~Enemy();
      virtual void TheenemyHealth(){}
     virtual int EnemyDamage(int EnemyAttack){
int  Attack = EnemyAttack;
     }
virtual int dropxp(int enemyxpdrop);



private:
  int Attackpower= 0;
  int Strenght = 0;
  int Enemyxp= 0;

   };

#endif // ENEMY_H
```

Comment: Your `Enemy` constructor takes two `int` arguments, but you're trying to call it with only one in the `Monster` constructor. I might also add that your approach to indentation is rather unique.

Answer (score 2):

Your enemy constructor is defined as `Enemy(int EnemyHealth,int EnemyMana);` but you are calling it with only one parameter in:

```
Monster::Monster(int MonsterHealth,int MonsterMana,int Monstersize) // implementation
: Health(MonsterHealth), Mana(MonsterMana), Enemy(Monstersize)
{}
```

Also your `Enemy` constructor does nothing:

```
Enemy::Enemy(int EnemyHealth,int EnemyMana)
{
    Attackpower;  // does nothing
    Strenght;  // does nothing
    Enemyxp;  // does nothing
}
```